# .htaccess whitelist file extensions - subfolders are blocked

Tags: regex, .htaccess

For security reasons I would like to block all files except certain extensions.
I am doing this with the following entry in .htaccess.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|js|css|ico|php|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|xls|xlsx|pdf|doc|docx|ppt|pptx)$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

My problem is, that regular requests to subfolders like http://mydomain/subfolder/ are blocked now as well. This is quite understandable, because the said request has no extension.

These are my tries:

```
^.*(\.html|\.js|\.css|\.ico|\.php|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.png|\.xls|\.xlsx|\.pdf|\.doc|\.docx|\.ppt|\.pptx)$
```

... (still blocking sub directories)

```
(\.(html|js|css|ico|php|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|xls|xlsx|pdf|doc|docx|ppt|pptx)?)$
```

... (does not block anything)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now been able to solve the problem by using 2 blocks of FilesMatch:

```
Order Allow,Deny 
Deny from all 
<FilesMatch "\.(html|js|css|ico|php|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|xls|xlsx|pdf|doc|docx|ppt|pptx)$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "^(\/)?$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

**Edit:**
Unfortunately the above solution fails if the subfolder has no trailing slash. The following solution now meets all my requirements and is much shorter:

```
### whitelist file extension which may be served
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(html|js|css|ico|php|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|xls|xlsx|pdf|doc|docx|ppt|pptx)$ [nc]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .* - [R=403,L]
```

The "-f" means that the condition is for files only, not folders.